# Resue of common structure of model with gson

Tags: android, json, retrofit, gson

I'm using retrofit and Gson converter. I have two JSON with same structure, like below.

JSON 1

```
{"message":"ok", 
 "code":200,
 "result":[{"name":"test"
            "id":121
            }]
}
```

JSON 2

```
{"message":"ok", 
 "code":200,
 "result":[{"first_name":"test"
            "last_name":"testing2"
            "middle_name":"test123"
            }]
}
```

For that I have created one common model class like

```
public void CommonModel {
    @SerializedName("code")
    public int code;

    @SerializedName("message")
    public String message;

    @SerializedName("result")
    public ResultModel result;

    public void ResultModel{
     public List<JSON1> json1;
     public List<JSON2> json2;
    }
}

public void JSON1 {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public int id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;
}

public void JSON2 {
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @SerializedName("last_name")
    public String lastName;

    @SerializedName("middle_name")
    public String middleName;
}
```

But it's not working. When I try the same concept in Jackson it works fine. I want to reuse the CommonModel for the response from the webservice. Please add comments if any one having solutions

Comment: It's the element `result` who is a list, not `JSON1` or `JSON2`

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier Could you please help to correct this

Answer (score 3):

Create common Model as below

```
public class Common {
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;

    @SerializedName("code")
    private String code;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

Create following Models for Json One extend Common Model on this class

```
public class JsonOne extends Common {

    @SerializedName("result")
    private List<JsonObjectOne> jsonObjectOneList;

    public List<JsonObjectOne> getJsonObjectOneList() {
        return jsonObjectOneList;
    }

    public void setJsonObjectOneList(List<JsonObjectOne> jsonObjectOneList) {
        this.jsonObjectOneList = jsonObjectOneList;
    }
}

public class JsonObjectOne {
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Create Models for Json Two extend Common Model on this class

```
public class JsonTwo extends Common {
    @SerializedName("result")
    private List<JsonObjectTwo> jsonObjectTwoList;

    public List<JsonObjectTwo> getJsonObjectTwoList() {
        return jsonObjectTwoList;
    }

    public void setJsonObjectTwoList(List<JsonObjectTwo> jsonObjectTwoList) {
        this.jsonObjectTwoList = jsonObjectTwoList;
    }
}

public class JsonObjectTwo {
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @SerializedName("last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @SerializedName("middle_name")
    private String middleName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the "result" in the common model itself and reuse that. I were looking for that

Comment: Yes, you can common result model, having all fields

Answer (score 1):

Of what i see, you have two solution.

**1) Use different class** :

```
public void ModelOne {
    @SerializedName("code")
    public int code;

    @SerializedName("message")
    public String message;

    @SerializedName("result")
    public List<ResultModel> result;

    public void ResultModelOne {
        @SerializedName("id")
        public int id;

        @SerializedName("name")
        public String name;
    }
}


public void ModelTwo {
    @SerializedName("code")
    public int code;

    @SerializedName("message")
    public String message;

    @SerializedName("result")
    public List<ResultModel> result;

    public void ResultModel {

        @SerializedName("first_name")
        public String firstName;

        @SerializedName("last_name")
        public String lastName;

        @SerializedName("middle_name")
        public String middleName;
    }
}
```

**2) Use one class, but parse in the response** :

```
public void Model {
    @SerializedName("code")
    public int code;

    @SerializedName("message")
    public String message;

    @SerializedName("result")
    public List<JSONObject> result;
}

public void ModelResultOne {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public int id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;
}

public void ModelResultTwo {
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @SerializedName("last_name")
    public String lastName;

    @SerializedName("middle_name")
    public String middleName;
}
```

Then :

```
List<ModelResultOne> list = new Gson.fromJson(result, new TypeToken<ArrayList<ModelResultOne.class>>() {}.getType());
```

or

```
List<ModelResultTwo> list = new Gson.fromJson(result, new TypeToken<ArrayList<ModelResultTwo.class>>() {}.getType());
```

Comment: First one, I were doing now. but i need to reuse the Model class as you suggest in the second option. Is there any way to parse on the response.

Comment: Edit your question, with the `onResponse()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
public void Model {
    @SerializedName("code")
    public int code;

    @SerializedName("message")
    public String message;

    @SerializedName("result")
    public ResultModel result;

public void ResultModel {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public int id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;

    @SerializedName("first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @SerializedName("last_name")
    public String lastName;

    @SerializedName("middle_name")
    public String middleName;
    }
}
```

And your response would be something like this.

```
Model res = response.body(); //response is of onResponse() method
ResultModel resultModel = res.getResultModel() //create getters and setters of model to get data

if (resultModel.getId != null){
    // Do your handling for id and name here
} else {
   // Do your handling for first name, middle name and last name
}
```

I hope this will work for you

Comment: Sorry to say that, I try with the about one already its not working.

Comment: It worked for me. so I thought maybe it will work for you too. Sorry

Comment: Actually there is no model reuse happening. I need to reuse the common model for Json1 and Json2

Comment: I just wanted to show you a way about the response handling with much lesser code and above mentioned approach worked for me. Btw best of luck with your project. :)

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer !!!!

```
public class CommonModel<T>
{
    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private int code;

    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private T result;
}

public void JSON1 {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public int id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;
}

public void JSON2 {
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @SerializedName("last_name")
    public String lastName;

    @SerializedName("middle_name")
    public String middleName;
}
```

**/////////////////////////////////////////
                Solution
/////////////////////////////////////////**

Call> getSetupJsonOne();

Call> getSetupJsonTwo();

Comment: Thanks everyone 

Micho,
Raphael Teyssandier,
Aman,
Muhammad Haseeb Khan